# Tense Agreement: 'hold' vs. 'held'

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses, tense-agreement

Which is correct in the following sentence and why?:

1. I met some people who 'hold' strong views on this issue;
2. I met some people who 'held' strong views on this issue.

I think "2" is correct in the perspective of tense agreement.

Answer (score 4):

Both are fine. *Held* is more natural in that construction, but when it's a property which is likely to continue to the present, *hold* is perfectly good, and draws attention to the fact that it is still the case.

As Alex_ander points out, you cannot in fact be sure that they still hold those views, so it may not be logically solid to say *hold*. If you met the people twenty years ago, *hold* would be strange. But if it was last week, it would be very surprising for them to have changed, so *hold* is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't be sure the people you met still keep the same opinion about some issue, the correct version is '**held**': it ties the action of the verb to the times when you **met** them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But someone insists that the word 'hold' be right because it is  an exception for tense agreement that 'some people' have 'strong views'. How about this?

Comment: I think it depends on that _issue_, is it something temporary and doubtful or constant (like the Earth going round the Sun).

Comment: Umm... Just one sentence is presented. Consequently, 'held' is true in general but sometimes 'hold' is used if the issue is constant, isn't it?